# Exporting scene during gameplay to FBX

Tags: unity, fbx, export

In Unity is there a way to add a menu button during gameplay that allows the player to export the current scene as an fbx file?

My googling and research shows that its possible to do this while *developing* the game but wondering if there is a way to add this functionality for the gameplay itself.

Any suggestions on how/if this can be done?

Comment: You can write your own script to iterate over all mesh components in the scene and serialize their data into whatever model file format you can dream up. What have you tried so far and where have you run into trouble?

Comment: ah, that's a good idea. i hadn't tried anything as i was at a loss where to start. thanks. will research and try that. thanks for the nudge in the right direction